# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' - NOT USING CLASS - Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter, arguments

due to my crude knowledge of Python, I am expecting more mistakes with the following script than just the positional argument error. Hence, I would very much appreciate any and all kind of observations/corrections. Again, I would like, if at all possible, to fix the positional argument error without having to use class. Thank you all very much.

```
# Python 3.5.1
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200+150+50")


total = 0.0
amount = 0.0
n = 0
x = 0

def total_amount():
    total = Entry.get()
    print ('got total!')

lb=ttk.Label(root, text="Enter total").grid(row=n, column=1)
totalEnt=ttk.Entry(root).grid(row=n, column=2)
button=ttk.Button(root, text='ok', command=total_amount).grid(row=n, column=3)

if total !=0:
    while True:
        if amount < total:
            while True:
                n = n + 1
                if x == 0:
                    def amount_entered(event):
                        amount = amount + Entry.get()
                        x = x + 1
                        print ('got amount!')
                    lb=ttk.Label(root, text="Enter amount").grid(row=n, column=1)
                    amountEnt=ttk.Entry(root).grid(row=n, column=2)
                    button=ttk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=amount_entered).grid(row=n, column=3)            
                elif x != 0:
                    print  ('gone from internal loop!')
                    break
        elif sub == total:
            print ('done!')
            break
        else:
            print ('sum of amount(s) cannot be greater than total')
else:
    pass


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Entry.get()`. You're trying to call `get` on the class itself, not an instance of the class.

Comment: `ttk` is meant as a replace for tkinter's widgets, so it's better to merge imports (but *-imports is discouraged by pep8). If you want so: `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter.ttk import *`. Or `import tkinter as tk` `import tkinter.ttk as ttk` and `tk.__dict__.update({k: v for k, v in ttk.__dict__.items() if k in ttk.__all__})`, then use as tk.

Comment: You should split lines with `Label(...).grid(...)` etc in two separate lines, cause grid method returns None, and you'll loose a way to access instance

Comment: I thought that I wasn't using a class. If I am, does it mean that a class is created without being formally defined? Or one is needed but it is missing?

Comment: I would like to achieve the same end without using a class. I am not planning to have several objects.

Comment: If you're using tkinter (or probably any gui package) you're using objects whether you like it or not.  IMO, using classes that are already designed for you, and are obviously useful, is the best way to start learning about object orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error message because .get() won't work on the class Entry.  It will work on an object such as totalEnt  that is an instance of Entry.

So you need

```
total = totalEnt.get()
```

Also, something like

```
totalEnt=ttk.Entry(root).grid(row=n, column=2)
```

won't work. If you need to give a name to an object such as totalEnt, you need to create it first, then call grid on it.

```
totalEnt=ttk.Entry(root)
totalEnt.grid(row=n, column=2)
```

You don't necessarily have to write any of your own classes, but to use tkinter (or probably any gui package in a object oriented language) you have to use some of the classes that are part of it. When you do something like

```
totalEnt=ttk.Entry(root)
```

You are creating an object, totalEnt, which is an instance of the class ttk.Entry. You imported the class from tkinter.